# Uso de sql_cache na query do MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Quando aprendi MySQL, me recomendaram usar a expressão `sql_cache` após o `SELECT`, algo assim:

```
"SELECT sql_cache * FROM tabela..."
```

Desde então passei a usar isso nos meus códigos, porém nunca ficou muito claro pra mim para quê isso serve, se tem a ver com cache, se acelera a consulta, enfim. Também nunca notei diferença alguma ocultando tal expressão da query. Eu uso ASP Clássico.

Qual é a função de usar `sql_cache`? É correto usar isso ou não faz diferença alguma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim tem um impacto na consulta caso ela seja efetuada novamente, e pode preceder com dois tipos as que armazenam a consulta em cache e uma segunda que não armazena e são usadas com baixa frequência.

> **Mas fique atento a versão do MySql** pois a partir da versão 5.7 ela será descontinuada, e na versão 8 será removida.
>
> SQL_CACHE

Geralmente, você não deve ter que usar isso em tudo. SQL_CACHE só é necessário se as consultas não forem armazenadas em cache por padrão, e que elas não estejam na configuração padrão da aplicação, como no caso de wordpress.

> NO_SQL_CACHE

É útil se você sabe que uma consulta específica não será usada novamente no futuro próximo, especialmente se o conjunto de resultados for grande. O objetivo é evitar a confusão do cache com resultados que não serão necessários novamente.

As aplicações tendem a fornecer o cache internamente como `wordpress` que trabalha com plugins específico para este fim, por este motivo o `mysql` tende a remover está função.

Vale resaltar se no seu caso a sua aplicação em `asp classico` possui este armazenamento de cache.

Aqui tem uma explicação na documentação do [MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-in-select.html), eu utilizo os dois métodos e a diferença é notável no processamento.

Comment: Legal. Deu pra entender.

Comment: @DvD inclusive estou estudando a respeito pois dou manutenção em um sistema antigo que possui algumas query bem pesada e agora estou estudando sobre cache no `php`, mas como na documentação menciona creio que a maioria das linguagens devam fornecer cache.